# Retrieve a variable from server using alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

this is my first attempt to retrieve a value using an alert box. Here what I am doing is having a file at the server and I want to retrieve that file value in an alert box.

Before that, I am able to get that value through a link. That working code is here-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <script>
    function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "localhost:8080/TemperatureReading/", true);
    xhttp.send();
    </script>
   <body>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/TemperatureReading/">test</a>
</body>
```

Request data

```
</html>
```

Now, what am I trying to do is have that value in an alert box every time I hit that button.

That code is here---

First I added a return statement in the function so that a variable is returned inside it.

```
 xhttp.send();
return variable;
```

Than, I added another function for alert box---

```
<script>
function myFunction() {


alert(variable);

});
</script>
```

and in the body, I added

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try</button>
```

But till now I am not succeeded in that.

I am not understanding what am doing wrong here.

Can anyone help me with this thing. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT** : I have edited the code. Also, I have to only create a HTML file. I am not generating the number. So, what I have to do is just give an HTML and with the help of retrieve value

Comment: There's **nothing** in this question that makes sense. The code fragments are wrong. The requirement is impossible to understand, and whatever it is you tried is missing. I suggest you study JavaScript from the start.

Comment: what is xhttp.responseText's value?

Comment: @Amit Sorry, may be because I have changed the code various times maybe that is reason I posted wrong code also I just want value coming from a file in alert box.

Comment: @user2181397 its an numerical value.

Comment: is it the value you want to alert?

Answer (score 0):

Do this when you get the response:

```
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
   if(window.localStorage){
     window.localStorage.setItem['resp'] = JSON.stringify(xhttp.responseText);//set it here
   }
}
```

now in the function where variable is required:

```
function myFunction() {
    if(window.localStorage){
       var resp = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem['resp']); // get it here
       alert(resp); // alert it here.
    }
}
```

Comment: so first I have to store in JSON than only I can retrieve??

Comment: @ShubhamVashishtha That is asynchrounous call so you have to store it somewhere.

Comment: @ShubhamVashishtha how do you call this function `loadDoc()` first time?

Comment: I just write an onclick 
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>
like this

Comment: Is that your real webpage? seems invalid to me.

Comment: I have edited question please see that also webpage is valid and before on clicking link it was giving value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112115/discussion-between-shubham-vashishtha-and-jai).